# iOS gesture recognition using camera

Tags: ios, camera, gesture-recognition

I implemented a basic gesture recognition on iPhone using the proximity sensor.
Now I need to go on iPad platform where no such sensor is available.

Is it possible to easily detect hand gesture using the camera on iOS ?
I saw OpenCV but it seems always used to detect faces, not hand gesture.

Answer (score 0):

"Easily"? No. Possible? Don't know.

Comment: Perhaps looking for detecting light intensity ? Don't know if such a functionality exists in iOS SDK.